# Reference to ' ' is ambiguous

Tags: c++

I am sorry but i don't know why this algorithm is not working.
The error at compiling is : "Reference to 'function' is ambiguous " and is on **y = function()** line, where I am calling the function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.141
float function(int g, int m, int s, float z)
{
    using namespace std;
    z = (g + m/60.0 + s/3600.0)*PI/180.0;
    return z;
}
int main()
{
     using namespace std;

    float y;
    int g,m,s;

    cout << "g = ";
    cin >> g;
    cout <<"m = ";
    cin >> m;
    cout<<"s= ";
    cin >>s;

    y = function();
    cout << "y= " << y << endl;
    //cout<< (g + m/60.0 + s/3600.0)*PI/180.0 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Vers2 - updated:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.141
float function(int g, int m, int s)
{
    //using namespace std;
    float z = (g + m/60.0 + s/3600.0)*PI/180.0;
    //std::cout << z <<std::endl;
    return z;
}
int main()
{
    // using namespace std;

    float y;
    int g,m,s;

    std::cout << "g = ";
    std::cin >> g;
    std::cout <<"m = ";
    std::cin >> m;
    std::cout<<"s= ";
    std::cin >>s;

    function();
  //  std::cout << "y= " << y << std::endl;
    //cout<< (g + m/60.0 + s/3600.0)*PI/180.0 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::function` exists, drop that `using namespace`.

Comment: I like how you have a function that takes four arguments so you gave it none!

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: That's because it obviously uses call-by-name. There's the real bug: The name `z`  cannot be found at the call site..

Comment: @damian: `z` does not appear to be an argument _to_ your function. If you need a local variable `z`, define it inside your function:. `{ float z = ...; return z; }`

Comment: @MSalters: What the heck is "call-by-name"?? You know we're talking about C++, yes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @molbdnilo: Right okay.

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: Could you please try renaming function to something else for a test?

Answer (score 19):

There is a member `function` in std and you inserted it into your namespace. Avoid using `using namespace std;`; you can import what you need this way:

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
```

Comment: @MSalters: I tried many ways to solve this, but none of them appears to work. I have deleted the "using namespace std" and put "std::" instead.Also, i have used z as local variable in my function and deleted from arguments.

Comment: @damian Please update your code so we can analyze it further.

Comment: @damian: Is it still the same error? I'd expect something about missing parameters

Comment: @ MikeMB: yes, it is the same error. Well, I had in my first version, z as parameter, but i have removed it and wrote it as local variable in my function. Please advise !

Answer (score 4):

I am getting a similar type of error while I used "prev" as a global variable of Node* type. Just **renaming** it with "prevv" solved issue in my case.

It is mostly due to the name of a "variable or function" is present in some library you used.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error message (for any of your versions with 3 different compilers), but the basic problem with your code is that you apparently assume the `g,m,s`-variables in your main functions are automatically used as parameters when you call `function()` just because they happen to have the same name.

This is NOT the case!

The variables inside your main and in the parameter list of function() are completely independent entities. The proper way to call the function and passing the right values is this:

```
y=function(g,m,s);
```

This basically copies the values stored inside the main `g,m,s` variables into the `g,m,s` parameters, which are accessed inside the function and after the function has completed, it then copies the value stored inside the variable you "return" from the function (here `z`) into the variable `y`.

This should work whether you are using `using namespace std;` or not, as your function has a completely different signature, But I'd still highly recommend to choose another name for your function.

I hope this doesn't sound like an insult, but I highly recommend that you read a introductory book about c++ programming, as it seems you are missing out on basic concepts of the language.