# How do I fix this error? Error - invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript?

Tags: c++

I seem to be having trouble with my code. This error Error - invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript keeps popping up and I don't know how to solve it. I need the variables for the solution to work and by removing them I would be working backwards. The error is found under the void convert2DimSort function, specifically the statement inside the nesting loop.

````
```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

//global
int i,j,temp;
int row,col;
const int sizeRow=4;
const int sizeCol=5;
char ans,choice,sagot;
const int size=20;
int elements[size];

//function
char getMenu(char ans);//returns the correct choice otherwise returns -1 if not.
void getInput(int list[],int dim);//input for both option 1 and 2
void getBubble(int list[],int dim);//perform the bubble sorting
void getSelect(int list[],int dim);//perform the selection sorting
void convert2DimSort(int list[],int dim);/*convert one dimensional to 2-dimensional for both 
option 1 and 2*/
void get2DOut(int list1[][sizeCol]);/*displaying the values in ascending and descending order 
2-D*/
void getHeap(int list3[],int dimen);//process heapyfication or heap sort 1-D


int main()
{
    //add code here
    //declaration statement

    //executable statement
    //add code here
    cout<<"-----------SORTING----------"<<endl
        <<"[1]bubble sort"<<endl
        <<"[2]selection sort"<<endl
        <<"[3]heap sort"<<endl
        <<"[4]QUIT"<<endl
        <<"-----------------------------"<<endl
        <<"Enter your choice:"<<endl;
    do
    {
        cin>>choice;
        if (choice<'1'||choice>'4')
            cout<<"Invalid range! Re-enter from 1 to 4 only:"<<endl;
    }while (choice<'1'||choice>'4');
    sagot=getMenu(choice);
        
    switch(sagot)
    {
        case '1'://bubblesort
        {    
            int elements[size]; 
            system ("CLS");
            cout<<"Processing Bubble Sorting Technique..."<<endl;
            getInput(elements,size);
            getBubble(elements,size);
        }
            break;
        case '2':
            {
                
                //add code here
                       //call getInput function
                  
            //call getSelect function
            //call convert2DimSort
            }
            break;
        case '3'://heapsort
                     {
                        //add code here
                        
                        cout<<endl<<"Heapyfied values ..."<<endl;
            //add code here
                     }
            break;
        case '4': cout<<"end of program.....\n";
                  exit(1);
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////
char getMenu(char ans)
{   
    return choice;
}
////////////////////////////////////
void getInput(int list[],int dim)// for both option 1 and 2 only
{
    cout<<"Enter 20 elements"<<endl;  
    for (i=0;i<20;i++) //input
    {
        cout<<"loc["<<i<<"]:";
        cin>>list[i];
        cout<<endl;
    }      
}
////////////////////////////////////////////
void getBubble(int list[],int dim)
{
    for (i=0;i<20;i++) //process-bubble sorting for ascending order
    {
        for (j=i+1;j<20;j++)
        {
            if (elements[j]<elements[i])
            {
                temp=elements[i];
                elements[i]=elements[j];
                elements[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////
void getSelect(int list[],int dim)
{
    //solution to selection sort  
            //add code here
    
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////
void convert2DimSort(int list[],int dim)
{
    int count;
    count=0;
    for (i=0;i<sizeRow;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<sizeCol;j++)
        {
            list[i][j]=elements[count++];
        }       
    }
    get2DOut(inList);    
}
void get2DOut(int list1[][sizeCol])
{
    
      cout<<"Ascending Order\n";
    //add code here
    cout<<"Ascending Order"<<endl; 
    for (i=0;i<sizeRow;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<sizeCol;j++)
        {
            cout<<left<<setw(5)<<list[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
     cout<<"\nDescending Order\n";
    //add code here
}
```
````

Comment: `list` is an `int*`, so `list[i]` is an `int`, so what would `list[i][j]` be?

Comment: an integer array as well?

Comment: Maybe this 'void convert2DimSort(int list[][sizeCol],int dim)'

Comment: @LearningITStudent No, `list[i]` is an `int`; you can't index it. `list[i][j]` is nonsense. What you're doing is similar to `int x = 1; x[0] = 2;`, which I'm sure you can see is not right.

Comment: @molbdnilo sorry slow learner. I only got what you mean now.

Comment: Next time always submit the complete error message. This even may help you understand the problem yourself!

Answer (score -1):

It is because you have the line `using namespace std` at the top. What this does is it tells the compiler that you want to try and pull every function, variable and all that from std.

std has a member called "size" so what you are doing is trying to use std's size instead of the variable that you created. So basically there are two solutions.

First off I'll put the solution I recommend, taking out the line `using namespace std` and just putting `std::` before the things in your code that actually need it. Even though it can get a bit tedious to put that before a lot of functions and everything, it can clean up your code a bit and give you a lot more freedom in what you name your functions. There are tones of other reasons as to why it can be bad practice to use this line as well which I haven't included here.

The second solution is a bit more of a "I can't be bothered doing this now" solution though it is just change the name of your size variable. I just stuck an a on the end of the variable to see if what I am saying would work and it seemed to work just fine. So I changed the variable name to `sizeA` since that is not referenced in std.

Also, if you decide to go with my first solution, the one I recommend, to find which ones need `std::` in front of them, you can just do that with trial and error. Most compilers will say something like `Function "size" is not defined. Did you mean "std::size"` or something similar to that.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387600/reference-to-is-ambiguous/29387712) is a link to a stack overflow question from a user with a very similar problem to you. The answer's don't give much detail though I thought I would include it just in case you find it helpful. The first answer on that page also gives a little alternative to `using namespace std`. The alternative goes for individual functions instead of everything so you can just put what you need under std.

Comment: Unfortunately since we were only taught to use using namespace std, that's only what we're allowed to use. My professor has very strict guidelines for activities. I even forgot to mention that we're not allowed to modify the function names and parameters.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with the problem.

Comment: @molbdnilo would you like to explain how it has nothing to do with it? I downloaded his code and the solution I explained compiled the code. So what I have done made the code work, how does that have nothing to do with it?

Comment: @CharedAssassin It has nothing to do with it because once you change it, there are three more compilation errors, one of which is the subject of this question. `using nemapace std` has no effect on whether indexing an `int` is possible.

Comment: @molbdnilo, fair point. I don't think my solution is what causes those errors though, like one of them was that a library that was needed wasn't even linked. It may have caused one or two of them though